# error message on change password code using php

Tags: php, error-code

I used a script for my user to change their password when logged in and when I tested it I showed this error message

> Notice: Undefined index: username in
>   /home/www/sitename/directory/changepw.php on line 8 Notice: Undefined
>   index: pin in /home/www/sitename/directory/changepw.php on line 9
>   Notice: Undefined index: newpassword in
>   /home/www/sitename/directory/changepw.php on line 10 Notice: Undefined
>   index: repeatnewpassword in /home/www/sitename/directory/changepw.php
>   on line 11

This is what I have in line 8,9,10and 11

```
 $username = $_POST['username']; 
 $pin = $_POST['pin']; 
 $newpassword = $_POST['newpassword']; 
 $repeatnewpassword = $_POST['repeatnewpassword'];
```

this is my HTML Code below

```
<style type="text/css">
    a:link {
       text-decoration: none;
    }
    a:visited {
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    a:hover {
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    a:active {
        text-decoration: none;
    }
</style>
<div id="inlogscherm">
<form name="form1" method="post" action="changepw.php">
    <div class="textm">Change password</div><br>
    <div class="text">Username:</div><div class="invulbalkje"><? echo    "{$_SESSION['username']}"; ?></div><br />
    <input name="username" type="text" id="username" value="<? echo   "{$_SESSION['username']}"; ?>">
  <div class="text">Password:</div><input name="pin" type="password"  id="pin" class="invulbalkje"><br />
    <div class="text">New Password:</div><input name="newpassword" type="password" id="newpassword" class="invulbalkje"><br />
    <div class="text">Repeat New Password:</div><input name="repeatnewpassword" type="password" id="repeatnewpassword" class="invulbalkje"><br />
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Change" class="button">
  <a href="logout.php">LOGOUT</a>
</form>
```

This is my php code below

```
<?php 
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    session_start();
    include 'db.php';


    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $pin = $_POST['pin'];
    $newpassword = $_POST['newpassword'];
    $repeatnewpassword = $_POST['repeatnewpassword'];

    $encrypted_password=md5($pin);
    $encrypted_newpassword=md5($newpassword);
    $wtbusers = '`wtbusers`';//this should be defined (change this to your whatever table name)

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT pin FROM $wtbusers WHERE     username='$username' and pin = '$pin'");
    if(!$result) 
    { 
        echo"<script>alert('Please Fill Form Correctly')</script>"; } 
        if(mysql_num_rows($result) != 0){
            if($newpassword == $repeatnewpassword){
            $sql=mysql_query("UPDATE $wtbusers SET pin='$pin' where  username='$username'");        
            if($sql) 
            { 
                echo"<script>alert('Successful')</script>";
            }
            else
            {

                echo"<script>alert('error')</script>";
            }       
        } else {

          echo"<script>alert('error_password_not_matched')</script>";
    }
} else {

    echo"<script>alert('Please Fill Form Correctly')</script>";
}

?>
```

Thank You.

Comment: Where is your HTML? these errors are obvious

Comment: It's clear you are not sending any POST data

Comment: your code is an invitation for SQL injection, XSS, etc

Comment: @Michelem please put me through on how to send a Post. Thank you

Comment: @Tina Is the php code on changepw.php file? And you have an error where you're trying to assign the values to username and password.

Comment: @HawasKaPujaari yes my php code is on changepw.php and even when i figured out the error it didnt update in my database

Answer (score 0):

All the other problems aside and addressing your actual question; There is no checking to see if a POST is being made that I can tell, so adding an @ symbol to those, like `$username = @$_POST['username'];` in your context is the fastest fix to get rid of them but I would recommend checking for a post first. [isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) is pretty good for that.

Alternatively you can turn off error reporting for notices by doing this

```
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
```

See [error_reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)

Answer (score 0):

That is not how you assign the value to a text field using sessions in PHP. It has syntactical error:

```
<input name="username" type="text" id="username" value="<? echo "{$_SESSION['username']}"; ?>">
```

I hope you have written `session_start();` in the beginning of your code (in every file you're using sessions in) or all of this (related to sessions) will be of no use.

Try this instead:

```
<?php
 session_start();
 $_SESSION['username'] = "mk";
 ?>
  <input name="username" type="text" id="username" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['username'];?>">
```

Now, you must use `isset` in a way so it doesn't run the php if it doesn't come from the form.

```
<?php 
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    session_start();
    include 'db.php'; // you might want to make corresponding changes here

if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $pin = $_POST['pin'];
    $newpassword = $_POST['newpassword'];
    $repeatnewpassword = $_POST['repeatnewpassword'];

    $encrypted_password=md5($pin);
    $encrypted_newpassword=md5($newpassword);
  // the rest of your code

   }
?>
```

**EDIT:**

Moving forward from the comments, this is the simplified/minor bugs fixed code:

```
<?php 
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    session_start();
    include 'db.php';


$servername = "localhost";
$username = "your_user_name_here";
$password = "your_pass_here";
$dbname = "your_db_name_here";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}


if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $pin = $_POST['pin'];
    $newpassword = $_POST['newpassword'];
    $repeatnewpassword = $_POST['repeatnewpassword'];

    $encrypted_password=md5($pin);
    $encrypted_newpassword=md5($newpassword);

   $wtbusers = '`your_table_name_here`';       //this should be defined (change this to your whatever table name)

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT pin FROM $wtbusers WHERE username= '$username' and pin = '$pin'");
    if(!$result) 

        echo"<script>alert('Please Fill Form Correctly')</script>";

        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
            if($newpassword == $repeatnewpassword){
            $sql=mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE $wtbusers SET pin= '$pin' WHERE username='$username'");        
            if($sql) 
                echo"<script>alert('Successful')</script>";
            else
                echo"<script>alert('error')</script>";
        } 
        else 
          echo"<script>alert('error_password_not_matched')</script>";
} 
else
    echo"<script>alert('Please Fill Form Correctly')</script>";

?>
```

Comment: thanks a million, i have an issue, its going successful but my database is not been updated with recent password

Comment: @Tina What errors are you getting? To start off `$sql=mysql_query();` this is wrong. Avoid using the _deprecated_ mysql funcitons and move to either `mysqli` or `PDO`.

Comment: @ HawasKaPujaari its not more showing any error message its just not updating my database after saying successful

Comment: also how do i avoid using the deprecated mysql function cos am already used to it. Thank you

Comment: @Tina you mean even after successful execution of `if($sql)` it does not show the updated record in the database?

Comment: @Tina Look for mysqli or PDO. There are many detailed posts available here

Comment: yes it doesnt show updated record after     if($sql)

Comment: @Tina `echo $sql=mysql_query("UPDATE $wtbusers SET pin='$pin' where  username='$username'");` this before `if($sql)` and see what you're doing

Comment: after echoed successful, it showed 1 . what does that signify? Thank you

Comment: @Tina _Err._ no. did you  echo your query to see what it displays? Like this:  `echo $sql=mysql_query("UPDATE $wtbusers SET pin='$pin' where username='$username'");`

Comment: i did this  {
    echo $sql=mysql_query("UPDATE $wtbusers SET pin='$pin' where   username='$username'");        
    if($sql)   it showed 1 after i tested the page
    {

Comment: @Tina I hope you did not write `{` before `echo` and plus. what did you see on the screen? A query string with values? Compare them the table and see if it matches the credentials that it should

Comment: this is what i did and what is saw on my page is just 1, i dont know what that means if(mysql_num_rows($result) != 0){
if($newpassword == $repeatnewpassword)
{
   echo $sql=mysql_query("UPDATE $wtbusers SET pin='$pin' where   username='$username'");        
    if($sql)

Comment: @Tina Oh my. no. You should rather be seeing something like `UPDATE wtbusers SET pin = 'yourr_pin_here' where username = 'your_username_here'` Ahh, what if the `$newpassword != $repeatnewpassword` then the `$sql` statement is never executed. Hence, no updation

Comment: please can u help me with the right code so i can input it? am still a learner. Thank you, am so grateful

Comment: @Tina well you got to debug, for starting just `echo $sql=mysql_query("UPDATE $wtbusers SET pin='$pin' where  username='$username'");` and remove the other `if-statements` and see what you get on the screen (try for both correct and incorrect passwords) that way you will see if it is to make any updation in the database or not

Comment: Nothing is working. Please do you have a code i can input in my site to enable users change their password?

Comment: @Tina Ah, Im sorry but that's not how it works around here. You should however look for more related stuff here: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_update.asp and try to grasp the idea of _how to correctly fetch the values from a form_ and then _save them in variables accordingly_ afterwards _if a condition matches, shoot a UPDATE query correctly_. That's all I can help you with, if you have more of the code in the future I'll be glad to do what I could. cheers :)

Comment: ok thanks dear @ HawasKaPujaari i really appreciate, can i ask for a favour for u to modify my code to help acchieve my aim?

Comment: @Tina Sure, I'll fix it using _mysqli_ and simplify it to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: thanks a million. Waiting patiently...

Comment: @Tina check the edit :)